# Customizing <pre> behavior

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm trying to format the `pre` element to follow these two behaviors, but can't figure out how to do it:

1. If the width of the `pre` element is less than the set width of its container, then horizontally align it with respect to its container.
2. If the width of the `pre` element is greater than the set width of its container, then set the `pre` element's `overflow-x` to scroll such that the scroll is on the pre element itself and not on the container.

The following below:

- Case 1 is an example of rule 1.
- Case 2 is an example of rule 2.
- Case 3 is an attempt to combine case 1 and 2, but the scroll is set on the
  container, not the `pre` element.

```css
body {
  background: cyan;
}

.c1, .c3 {
  text-align: center;
}

pre[class^='case'] {
  background: lightgreen;
}

.case1 {
  text-align: initial;
  display: inline-block;
}

.case2 {
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.case3 {
  text-align: initial;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class='c1'>
  <pre class='case1'>
          1
        1   1
      1   1   1 
    1   2   1   1
  1   2   2   1   1
1   3   3   2   1   1
  </pre>
</div>

<div class='c2'>
  <pre class='case2'>
          1
        1   1
      1   1   1 
    1   2   1   1
  1   2   2   1   1
1   3   3   2   1   1       testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttest
  </pre>
</div>

<div class='c3'>
  <pre class='case3'>
          1
        1   1
      1   1   1 
    1   2   1   1
  1   2   2   1   1
1   3   3   2   1   1       testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttest
  </pre>
</div>
```

As an alternative, if it is possible to horizontally center the contents of the `pre` element, this would work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
pre {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: initial;
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

Applied to your snippet:

```css
body {
  background: cyan;
}

.c1, .c3 {
  text-align: center;
}

pre[class^='case'] {
  background: lightgreen;
}

pre {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: initial;
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class='c1'>
  <pre class='case1'>
          1
        1   1
      1   1   1 
    1   2   1   1
  1   2   2   1   1
1   3   3   2   1   1
  </pre>
</div>

<div class='c2'>
  <pre class='case2'>
          1
        1   1
      1   1   1 
    1   2   1   1
  1   2   2   1   1
1   3   3   2   1   1       testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttest
  </pre>
</div>

<div class='c3'>
  <pre class='case3'>
          1
        1   1
      1   1   1 
    1   2   1   1
  1   2   2   1   1
1   3   3   2   1   1       testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttest
  </pre>
</div>
```